# Error in parsing JSON with Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've been looking on the web for an answer but as a French newbie in Swift, I didn't find anything.
I'm getting and error in parsing when trying to decode [my JSON file](http://celestinlebehot.com/saintlobus-export-2.json).

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

struct Station: Decodable {
    let ID: Int
    let name: String
    let lines: String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let urlString = "https://celestinlebehot.com/saintlobus-export-2.json"
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            return
        }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }


            do {
                let stations = try JSONDecoder().decode([Station].self, from: data)
                print("\(stations)")

            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("error in parsing",jsonErr)
            }
            }.resume()

    }

}
```

Here's the error I get when running the app :

> error in parsing valueNotFound(Swift.KeyedDecodingContainer, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0))], debugDescription: "Cannot get keyed decoding container -- found null value instead.", underlyingError: nil))

What's the matter ?

- If you have any idea of how to make a public transportation database with JSON (with bus stops coordinates and schedule), I'd be up to listen advices, because I'm 18 ans just starting coding with Swift (Saint-Lô Citybus app on App Store).

Thanksss :)

Comment: The code is running perfect with the JSON file using, It is only because of no value for the key. The above solution will surely work in that case.

Comment: The code is correct and is supposed to work. Is this the real code?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've created a new project and paste this code in it and it worked. How? I don't know. But it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The code seems fine but check with your json file as the error says you do not have value for a particular key.And also set your json variables to optional .